# rails validate max number in collection with relation has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to validate the number max of team who can join a tournament. (max_nb_team is a field in tournament who set the limit)
The db relation are like this.
Team <-> TeamTournament <-> Tournament

But currently my validate count all the teams already join (write in db) but not the team who are joining.
So when I have 5 teams on 5 in a tournament and I add one more, validate count 5 and don't launch a rollback.

I made my validate in tournament and associate this validate in team_tournament.

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_tournament, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :team_tournament

  validate :validate_max_nb_team

  def suscribe_teams(array_team)
    array_team.each do |t|
      teams << t
    end
  end

  private
  def validate_max_nb_team
    length_remaining_teams = teams.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).size
    # length_remaining_teams return five when I'm adding the 6th
    errors.add :max_nb_team, "Max number team has been reached" if length_remaining_teams > max_nb_team
  end
end

class TeamTournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :tournament

  validates_associated :tournament
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_tournament, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tournaments, through: :team_tournament
end

class TournamentsController < ApplicationController
  def add_teams
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
    authorize! :edit, @tournament
    names = teams_params

    teams = []
    names.reject { |p| p.blank? }.each do |n|
      teams << Team.create(name: n)
    end

    begin
      @tournament.suscribe_teams(teams)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
      return redirect_to(:back, alert: "Max number team has been reached")
    end
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private
  def teams_params
    params.require(:teams)
  end
end
```

So I would like to count the teams who are joining in the validate. Maybe it's not the good way, if so thanks to say me how manage this issues.

Comment: You need to say more about what you want to happen, ie your requirements.  Eg, if there are 3 teams already, and someone tries to add 5 teams, do you want to add 2 of them?  or add no teams, and tell them to reduce the number and try again?

Comment: Also, what is "max_nb_team"?  is it a field in the database?

Comment: The max_nb_team is a field (int) of tournament. If there is place for some but not all he let join until there is no place left.